# how to select column names for the values those are bold?

Tags: sql

```
Cong    BJP      AAP     Winner   Win By
25554   36985    **26929**   BJP      10056
19753   **24569**    36239   AAP      11670
```

Using Sql server 2008, This is a voting table and I want to select second max number of vote from Cong, BJP and AAP columns with columns name of result value
returns
Expected result:

```
Againstvote  AgainstPartyName
26929           AAP
24569           BJP
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking.  Can you provide the layout of the table and any SQL that you have attempted?

Comment: share your email id , i will send you

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. Please rephrase...

Comment: What SQL product and what version thereof are you using?

Comment: Using Sql server 2008, This is a voting table and I want to select second max number of vote from Cong, BJP and AAP columns with columns name of result value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
   case
      when BJP between AAP and Cong then BJP 
      when AAP between BJP and Cong then AAP 
      else Cong
   end as AgainstVote,
   case
      when BJP between AAP and Cong then 'BJP' 
      when AAP between BJP and Cong then 'AAP' 
      else 'Cong'
   end as AgainstPartyName
from tab
```

Comment: Really Help full Thanks Dnoeth.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want a way to treat your column name as part of your data. I'd say, that speaks about a sub-optimal design. Anyway, in your particular case there's an UNPIVOT clause to the rescue:

```
SELECT
  Votes     AS AgainstVotes,
  PartyName AS AgainstPartyName
FROM dbo.atable AS t
UNPIVOT (
  Votes FOR PartyName in (BJP, AAP)
) AS u
WHERE PartyName <> Winner
;
```

The UNPIVOT clause converts your data set into this:

```
Cong   PartyName  Votes  Winner  Win By
-----  ---------  -----  ------  ------
25554  BJP        36985  BJP     10056
25554  AAP        26929  BJP     10056
19753  AAP        36239  AAP     11670
19753  BJP        24569  AAP     11670
```

The WHERE clause then filters out rows with the winning votes, keeping the participants that lost.